How do I remove the Elder Scroll (Dragon) from my inventory after completing Dawnguard?
I have completed the entire main quest line where I take the Elder Scroll (Dragon) to Paarthurnax and then completed the Dawnguard quest line (as far as I know). I picked the vampire's side; however, I still can't remove the scroll from my inventory to place it inside Tel Aschen.
Can someone please clarify if there is more to the Dawnguard quest line after killing Harkon to finally complete the quest? I want to be able to add the Elder Scroll to Tel Aschen.

What's this Tel Aschen? Is this a location added with a mod? Afaik the only way to remove that item from your inventory is Dexion Evicus, but that's not possible if you chose to side with vampires.

By "Tel Aschen", do you mean this mod? Tel Aschan - Mage Tower Home

This question is similar to: What am I meant to do with Elder Scroll (Dragon) after completing Dawnguard? If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
